# How can I match partial version strings when using the Ant 'copy' task?

Tags: ant

I have a directory structure like this

```
client/lib
a.jar
b-4.3.jar
c-1.2.jar
d-4.3.jar
e.jar
```

I need to copy the jars - some without version, and some with.
The only information that I have is version number, and that is stored in a variable.

The version number I have is in a property, and has three fields - '4.3.1'
The version that the jars have is just the *first two fields* from the property value (i.e. 4.3 in this case).
I need all jars that starting with two digits that my property has, and some of the jars without version.
For example, from above directory structure I need:

```
b-4.3.jar
d-4.3.jar
e.jar
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) [propertyregex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task.  Perhaps something like this:

```
<property name="version" value="4.3.1" />
<propertyregex override="yes" property="version2" input="${version}"
               regexp="(.*).([^.]+)"
               replace="\1" />

<fileset id="my_jars" dir="client/lib">
    <include name="*${version2}.jar" />
    <include name="e.jar" />
</fileset>

<copy todir="to_dir">
    <fileset refid="my_jars" />
</copy>
```